# MySQL: select * from table where col IN (null, "") possible without OR

Tags: mysql, null

Is it somehow possible to do a select for empty strings and NULL values in MySQL without using or?

This:

```
   select * from table where col IN (null, "");
```

doesn't work, it ignores the null (or possibly matches it with the string 'null').

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   COALESCE(col, '') = ''
```

Note, however, than `OR` query will be much more efficient if the column is indexed:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   col = '' OR col IS NULL
```

This will use `ref_or_null` access path on the index.

If you need to select from a list of values along with `NULLs`, just put all not-null values into the list and add a single `OR IS NULL` condition:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   col IN ('val1', 'val2', 'val3') OR col IS NULL
```

This will use an index on `col` as well.

Comment: i left it out from consciseness, but in practice my query would be:
select * from table where col IN ("", NULL, "a", "b", "c", "few more options");

would this still be correctly using an index?
( col in (list) or IS NULL )

Comment: Will it use index in the case NULL is inside IN() or only when NULL is ORed with IN()?

Comment: @henno: `col IN (NULL)` will never match, even if `col` is a null. It does not depend on whether it uses index or not.

Comment: I guess the reason is that the internal logic of Mysql will see that a value is null and not bother testing whether it is in the listed values?

Comment: @MaxWilliams: reason for what?

Comment: @Quassnoi The reason why "col IN (NULL) will never match, even if col is a null.".  If I was in a regular programming language, and had an array with `[nil]` and tested if `nil` was in that array, i'd expect it to return true.  So mysql's behaviour here is arguably unintuitive.  I was just speculating about the mechanism which makes it behave that way.

Comment: @MaxWilliams: the reason is that SQL is designed this way. `NULL = NULL` is not true or false, it's NULL. If you do a query like this: `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE col = NULL`, it will never return any records, not even the records with the value of `col` set to NULL. All SQL databases behave like this, not just MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is looking for this solution, as I was; if you're searching by more than one column, you need to group the where/or statement in parenthesis.

This will not return the results you expect:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE col1 IN ('val1', 'val2') OR col1 IS NULL AND col2 IN ('val3', 'val4')
```

The "OR col1 IS NULL" will completely override your "AND col2 IN" statement.

Putting all of the conditions for col1 inside parenthesis will work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE (col1 IN ('val1', 'val2') OR col1 IS NULL) AND col2 IN ('val3', 'val4')
```

It took me a while to consider trying this, because (at least in my experience) you don't typically put WHERE statements in parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

That's work great for me

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE IFNULL(col1, '-') IN('val1', 'val2', '-') AND col2 IN ('val3', 'val4')
```