# SELECT FROM WHERE = true

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

I am trying to select database entries where a field is filled in. The database has 2 ways of inserting data, one enters a comment and one does not, i am lookin to only select rows that have comments filled in.

```
 $requete = "SELECT * FROM daysoff WHERE comment = true ORDER BY id";
```

where is this going wrong? or what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: What is the value of the `comment` field when it is not filled in?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql: select \* from table where col IN (null, "") possible without OR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147824/mysql-select-from-table-where-col-in-null-possible-without-or)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try:

```
$requete = "SELECT * FROM daysoff WHERE comment IS NOT NULL ORDER BY id";
```

Comment: thanks but this is returning rows that do not have `comment` set

Comment: If so, try: `$requete = "SELECT * FROM daysoff WHERE comment <> '' ORDER BY id";`

Answer (score 0):

You must try this

```
$requete = "SELECT * FROM daysoff WHERE comment IS NOT NULL AND comment != '' ORDER BY id";
```