# How to include NULL into ENUM on select?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sql-null

My field country in ENUM type: (mysql - mariaDB)

```
`country` enum('France','Belgique','Suisse') DEFAULT NULL;
```

Is there a way to include NULL into a select ?

```
Select * from users where country in ('France','Suisse', NULL, '') ?
```

I would like to retrieve users from France, Suisse or those who did not specify the country (NULL)

Of course I can still use :

```
Select * from users where (country in ('France','Suisse') OR country is NULL)
```

But this is quite verbose for me

Comment: Try like this: `SELECT * FROM  users WHERE COALESCE(country, '') IN ('France','Suisse','')`

Comment: Why do you have `''` in the list of values? That's not a possible value of the ENUM.

Comment: I just tried with NULL and with '' and did not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql: select \* from table where col IN (null, "") possible without OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147824/mysql-select-from-table-where-col-in-null-possible-without-or)

Comment: *"But this is quite verbose for me"* Well that is how SQL language works as `SELECT` in SQL is declarative in nature where you define *"what you want to have"* and not *"how to get it"* as that part is defined with the `CREATE TABLE ...` and the SQL engine which knows how to handle both parts into a resultset..

Comment: You could try to use [ProxySQL](https://www.proxysql.com/) to add MySQL query rewrite rules..Might be more easy when you make a rewrite rule like `Select * from users where (country in ('France','Suisse')) UNION ALL Select * from users where country is NULL` when `Select * from users where (country in ('France','Suisse'))` is used.. Only problem the debugging can be a nightmare, as i am not sure if or how you can ask ProxySQL how a rewrite looks like as MySQL supports `EXPLAIN <query>; SHOW WARNINGS:`  then you could see a rewrite when it happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `ENUM` so that `''` is the default and have it mean 'not specified'.

That is:

```
ENUM ('', 'France','Belgique','Suisse') NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
```

Then this works:

```
in ('France','Suisse', '')
```

(I like to have the first item in the declaration be the default.)

Comment: @Barmar copy-paste mistake.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `IFNULL()` function to specify a default value that matches one of the values in the `IN` list. You can use a value that doesn't actually exist in the `ENUM` to distinguish it.

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE IFNULL(country, 'unspecified') IN ('France', 'Suisse', 'unspecified');
```

Comment: @RickJames I've changed it to use a distinct value, this should be less confusing. In practice, your method is how I would actually do it.